# Add a hyperlink to a NetSuite PDF Invoice?

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to add a hyperlink to a NetSuite PDF Invoice?  Ideally I would like the hyperlink to contain the followng the internalid of the Invoice along with the Invoice total:

```
https://example.com/link?internalid=123456&total=123.56
```

I have tried the following:

1. Create a new Transaction Body Field with type 'Hyperlink'
2. Added a link under the Validation & Defaulting tab
3. Edited our Invoice Layout Custom PDF and added that custom element.

My new custom element does not contain a hyperlink and I am wondering if what I want to do is indeed possible.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue of adding a hyperlink to an Advanced PDF/HTML Template for a transaction custom record type.  I changed the custom field to be "Inline HTML" and it showed as expected.

Comment: That's a shame - we don't have the Advanced PDF/HTML Template so it didn't work.  Thanks for sharing, perhaps we will puchase this in the future.

Comment: Aww that is a shame, sorry about that.  Odd the field won't print on a basic template.  Perhaps try making the filed a text field, since the link being clickable (field type = hyperlink) isn't really applicable on the printed form...